# SDImageCache not working

Tags: ios, caching, sdwebimage

I am encountering a very strange issue in my application.
I have used SDWebImage in the application, to download the images to cache, when network present and then retrieve the images from the cache, when absent.

The SDWebImage works perfectly in case of UITableViews. One can even see the stored/cached image files in the iPhone Simulator folder.
And then theres this one piece of code, that is troubling me.

I am displaying a simple imageview, and caching the image from the network.
The image is displayed properly, when network is present.
But in case of no connectivity, nothing is displayed.
Am assuming, that the caching is not taking place.

**Lines of code**

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [im setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kImgaePath,[[marrresultingArraySet objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:kIndex_RecipeImage_Local]] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_imagepng.jpg"]];});
```

Comment: I think their is no need to add the code in any queue.

Comment: That would not make much sense. Anyhow, previously the code was written minus the queue mode. Still no success.

Comment: make sure the outlet is connected and try to run URL of image on browser, you must get an image on browser.

Comment: What you are asking, would have occurred even in Online mode. But, this problem occurs, only when offline. Please read the info stated above, for more details regarding the problem.